# Get url params in view page of zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have url as http://mydomain.com/contact?status=1. 
How to check the status parameter is set and get value of status in zend view using zend framework?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the view parameter in controller: like

```
$this->view->status = $this->_getParam('status');

//and in view
echo $this->status;
```

OR

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getParam('status');
```

For flash messages, you can use FlashMessenger helper, like:
//set up flash messenger

```
$flashMessenger = $this->_helper->FlashMessenger;
$flashMessenger->addMessage('some message here');
```

See here:: [ActionHelpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html)

Comment: In zend framework, whether any flashes messages properties is there, like a message will be given as flash after redirect of page.